# drupal - settings.php - specify schema

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to connect Drupal to an external Database and i need to specify the schema on the settings.php (drupal-7.28/sites/default/settings.php) otherwise Drupal schema module connects by default the 'public' schema. I tried, whithout succes, with the following code:

```
 $databases['conservation']['default'] = array(
     'database' => 'conservation',
     'schema' => 'projects_test1',
      'username' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      'password' => 'xxx',
      'host' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx',
      'port' => '5432',
      'driver' => 'pgsql',
      'prefix' => array(
     'default'   => 'projects_test1.',
     'users'     => 'shared.',
     'sessions'  => 'shared.',
     'role'      => 'shared.',
     'authmap'   => 'shared.',
   )

);
```

I have done some googling but haven't found anybody trying to do this as yet. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try Schema module and Data Tables module with the views module to able to create views for external data visualization in Drupal 7.